# While using an anchor tag, is it possible to have extra space above the top of the link?

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

```css
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    
}
#header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color:rgb(0, 255, 170);
    height:60px;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.main-list{
    top: -57.5px;
    position:relative;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-width: 1%;
    
}
.list-item{
    
    margin: 10px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    flex: border-box;
}
a:hover{
    background-color: gray;
    color: black;
}
#header h1{
    margin:0;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
.height{
    height: 700px
}
section{
    margin: -32px 10px 10px 10px;
    
    
    padding: 10px;
}
#help{
    padding-top: 70px;
    margin: 0;
}
#contact{
    padding-top: 70px;
}
#about{
    margin:0;
    padding-top: 70px;
}
#home{
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="header">
      <h1>Website</h1>
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul class="main-list">
          <li>
            <a class="list-item button" href="#top" target="_top">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="list-item button" href="#about" target="_top">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="list-item button" href="#help" target="_top">Help</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="list-item button" href="#contact" target="_top"
              >Contact</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="content">
    </br>
      <h1 id="about">About me</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet at natus vitae voluptate ex ipsam aspernatur distinctio dolores? Neque, repudiandae.
      </p>

      <h1 id="help">Help</h1>
      <div class="height"></div>
      <a id="return" href="#top-content" target="_top">Return to top</a>
      <div class="height"></div>
      <p1 id="contact">Contact</p1>
      <div class="height"></div>
      <div class="height"></div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am tinkering with html and css.  I currently have a fixed header at the top of the page.  I do not want to have extra padding that will make it look awkward while scrolling through the page. Is there any way to provide some extra space when the link is clicked? I saw something about clip-path but I am not sure the syntax for this markup.

Comment: may i have a look at the code?

Comment: The code has been uploaded

Comment: have you tried `padding-top: 1rem`?

Comment: @chovy just tried, no luck there

Comment: Is your question about adding sort of padding to the scroll position when rescrolling the page to a heading so it doesn't get blocked by the fixed header?

Comment: @WillD yes as if there was padding there to make sure the fixed header did not cover it

Comment: https://getpublii.com/blog/one-line-css-solution-to-prevent-anchor-links-from-scrolling-behind-a-sticky-header.html <this will be what you need